# Webkit Animated Div's Border

Tags: jquery, webkit

I'm coding a photographer's website right now. It has relatively heavy images in background with fade effects. In the gallery page *("Galeri" link on the menu)*, when content is being animated, content's border acts weird. [Here](http://oi49.tinypic.com/29upwk8.jpg) is the screenshot of it. You can check yourself [here](http://office701.com/web/sdr/).

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out that this was happening because of translate3d feature of CSS3.